# Why imagecreatefromjpeg not working for .jpg extension?

Tags: thumbnails, imagejpeg, imagecreatefromjpg

I have code for thumbnails which works great for gif, png and jpeg files but not for jpg.

Please help me how to make it work for jpg.

I get no errors and nothing in log file.

```
function create_thumb($src,$dest,$desired_width = false, $desired_height = false){
if (!$desired_height&&!$desired_width) return false;
$fparts = pathinfo($src);
$ext = strtolower($fparts['extension']);
if (!in_array($ext,array('gif','jpg','png','jpeg'))) return false; 
if ($ext == 'gif') $resource = imagecreatefromgif($src);
else if ($ext == 'png') $resource = imagecreatefrompng($src); 
else if ($ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'jpeg') $resource = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
$width  = imagesx($resource);
$height = imagesy($resource); 
if(!$desired_height) $desired_height = floor($height*($desired_width/$width));
if(!$desired_width)  $desired_width  = floor($width*($desired_height/$height));
$virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width,$desired_height);
imagecopyresized($virtual_image,$resource,0,0,0,0,$desired_width,$desired_height,$width,$height);
$fparts = pathinfo($dest);
$ext = strtolower($fparts['extension']); 
if (!in_array($ext,array('gif','jpg','png','jpeg'))) 
    $ext = 'jpg';$dest = $fparts['dirname'].'/'.$fparts['filename'].'.'.$ext;
if ($ext == 'gif') imagegif($virtual_image,$dest); 
else if ($ext == 'png') imagepng($virtual_image,$dest,1); 
else if ($ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'jpeg') imagejpeg($virtual_image,$dest,72); 
return array( 'width'     => $width, 'height'    => $height, 'new_width' => $desired_width, 'new_height'=> $desired_height, 'dest'      => $dest ); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I find solution for me...

```
$dest = $fparts['dirname'].'/'.$fparts['filename'].'.gif';
imagewebp($virtual_image,$dest,80);
```

Every image is gif and very small size ;)

Hope it will help to somebody.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).